# Cannot import tensorflow: No module named 'tensorflow' in Spyder under Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, modulenotfounderror

I have seen this problem happen recurrently, though none of the solutions are fully relevant to me. I have installed Tensorflow as :

`conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow`

`conda activate tensorflow_env`

Then I changed to this tensorflow_env inside **Anaconda Navigator(gui)**, and installed Spyder there. Now inside Spyder I am getting this error while importing tensorflow:

*ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)*

*in----> 1 import tensorflow as tf*

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'*

1) Python version(used by Spyder) is Python 3.7.6. I should mention that doing `print(sys.executable)` inside and outside the conda environment mention different paths.

2) I have seen this exact installation procedure work for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Can someone please help in troubleshooting this?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: @Yoskutik That worked! I did not do it initially as I read that it might lead to unstable system! Anyway, I installed it under a virtual environment and changed my Spyder's interpreter to that location. Works till now. Thanks :)